# memset char * with Integer

Tags: c, memory, endianness, memset

I have to memset 4 bytes in a `char` * with an integer.

For exemple I have an integer `int i = 3276854 (0x00320036)` and a `char header[54] = {0}`. I have to write i at header + 2, as if I print memory from header[2] to header[6], I get :

> 0032 0036

I tried this:

```
memset(&header[2], i, 1);
```

But it seems to put only the last byte into header, I get :

> 0036 0000

I also tried:

```
memset(&header[2], i, 4);
```

But it fill each byte with the last byte of i, I get :

> 3636 3636

I also tried to use binary masks like that :

```
ft_memset(&header[2], (int)(54 + size) & 0xff000000, 1);
ft_memset(&header[3], (int)(54 + size) & 0x00ff0000, 1);
ft_memset(&header[4], (int)(54 + size) & 0x0000ff00, 1);
ft_memset(&header[5], (int)(54 + size) & 0x000000ff, 1);
```

I get :

> 3600 0000.

So I don't know how I can get my `0032 0036`, or at least `3600 3200` (maybe there is a thing with little and big endian into that, because I run it under MacOS, which is big endian).

Comment: `memcpy` is the function you are looking for

Comment: And a `char *` array is probably not what you want. Should probably be `char` array.

Comment: Oh, thats a mistake, I'm using a char*, not a char** !

Comment: I didn't even thought about memcpy, I try it

Comment: @Bccyv read closely the first few lines if [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) and [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Comment: Seems more appropriate, yes !

Comment: @M.M No, because `memcpy` needlessly causes a tight coupling between the code and CPU endianess. Bit shift is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Lundin they weren't clear about which ordering they wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memset` fills memory with a constant byte value. The second parameter (of type `int`) is converted to an `unsigned char` value.

You could use `memcpy` like this:

```
memcpy(&header[2], &i, sizeof(i));
```

However, it depends what exactly you are trying to achieve. If the header needs the integer to be in a particular format, you may need to convert the value in some way. For example, if the value needs to be big-endian (which is also known as "network byte order" in several Internet protocols), you can convert it with the `htonl` function:

```
uint32_t bi = htonl(i);
memcpy(&header[2], &bi, sizeof(bi));
```

(The `htonl` function is defined by `#include <arpa/inet.h>`.)

Also check the newer byte order conversion functions `htobe16`, `htole16`, `be16toh`, `le16toh`, `htobe32`, `htole32`, `be32toh`, `le32toh`, `htobe64`, `htole64`, `be64toh`, and `le64toh` declared by:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <endian.h>
```

These convert between host byte order and little-endian byte order, or between host byte order and big-endian byte order, and work on `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` values, depending on the function name.

If there are no equivalents to those byte-order conversion functions provided on your system the following non-optimized, but portable (on implementations that support `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`) functions may be used:

**myendian.h**

```
#ifndef MYENDIAN_H__INCLUDED_
#define MYENDIAN_H__INCLUDED_

#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t my_htobe16(uint16_t h16);
uint16_t my_htole16(uint16_t h16);
uint16_t my_be16toh(uint16_t be16);
uint16_t my_le16toh(uint16_t le16);

uint32_t my_htobe32(uint32_t h32);
uint32_t my_htole32(uint32_t h32);
uint32_t my_be32toh(uint32_t be32);
uint32_t my_le32toh(uint32_t le32);

uint64_t my_htobe64(uint64_t h64);
uint64_t my_htole64(uint64_t h64);
uint64_t my_be64toh(uint64_t be64);
uint64_t my_le64toh(uint64_t le64);

#endif
```

**myendian.c**

```
#include "myendian.h"

union swab16
{
    uint16_t v;
    uint8_t b[2];
};

union swab32
{
    uint32_t v;
    uint8_t b[4];
};

union swab64
{
    uint64_t v;
    uint8_t b[8];
};

static uint16_t xbe16(uint16_t x)
{
    union swab16 s;

    s.b[0] = (x >> 8) & 0xffu;
    s.b[1] = x & 0xffu;
    return s.v;
}

static uint16_t xle16(uint16_t x)
{
    union swab16 s;

    s.b[0] = x & 0xffu;
    s.b[1] = (x >> 8) & 0xffu;
    return s.v;
}

static uint32_t xbe32(uint32_t x)
{
    union swab32 s;

    s.b[0] = (x >> 24) & 0xffu;
    s.b[1] = (x >> 16) & 0xffu;
    s.b[2] = (x >> 8) & 0xffu;
    s.b[3] = x & 0xffu;
    return s.v;
}

static uint32_t xle32(uint32_t x)
{
    union swab32 s;

    s.b[0] = x & 0xffu;
    s.b[1] = (x >> 8) & 0xffu;
    s.b[2] = (x >> 16) & 0xffu;
    s.b[3] = (x >> 24) & 0xffu;
    return s.v;
}

static uint64_t xbe64(uint64_t x)
{
    union swab64 s;

    s.b[0] = (x >> 56) & 0xffu;
    s.b[1] = (x >> 48) & 0xffu;
    s.b[2] = (x >> 40) & 0xffu;
    s.b[3] = (x >> 32) & 0xffu;
    s.b[4] = (x >> 24) & 0xffu;
    s.b[5] = (x >> 16) & 0xffu;
    s.b[6] = (x >> 8) & 0xffu;
    s.b[7] = x & 0xffu;
    return s.v;
}

static uint64_t xle64(uint64_t x)
{
    union swab64 s;

    s.b[0] = x & 0xffu;
    s.b[1] = (x >> 8) & 0xffu;
    s.b[2] = (x >> 16) & 0xffu;
    s.b[3] = (x >> 24) & 0xffu;
    s.b[4] = (x >> 32) & 0xffu;
    s.b[5] = (x >> 40) & 0xffu;
    s.b[6] = (x >> 48) & 0xffu;
    s.b[7] = (x >> 56) & 0xffu;
    return s.v;
}

uint16_t my_htobe16(uint16_t h16)
{
    return xbe16(h16);
}

uint16_t my_htole16(uint16_t h16)
{
    return xle16(h16);
}

uint16_t my_be16toh(uint16_t be16)
{
    return xbe16(be16);
}

uint16_t my_le16toh(uint16_t le16)
{
    return xle16(le16);
}

uint32_t my_htobe32(uint32_t h32)
{
    return xbe32(h32);
}

uint32_t my_htole32(uint32_t h32)
{
    return xle32(h32);
}

uint32_t my_be32toh(uint32_t be32)
{
    return xbe32(be32);
}

uint32_t my_le32toh(uint32_t le32)
{
    return xle32(le32);
}

uint64_t my_htobe64(uint64_t h64)
{
    return xbe64(h64);
}

uint64_t my_htole64(uint64_t h64)
{
    return xle64(h64);
}

uint64_t my_be64toh(uint64_t be64)
{
    return xbe64(be64);
}

uint64_t my_le64toh(uint64_t le64)
{
    return xle64(le64);
}
```

**Test harness: myendiantest.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "myendian.h"

#define TEST(n, fn, v) \
    printf("%s(%#" PRIx##n ") = %#" PRIx##n "\n", #fn, (v), (fn)(v))

int main(void)
{
    const uint16_t t16 = UINT16_C(0x1234);
    const uint32_t t32 = UINT32_C(0x12345678);
    const uint64_t t64 = UINT64_C(0x123456789abcdef);

    TEST(16, my_htobe16, t16);
    TEST(16, my_htole16, t16);
    TEST(16, my_be16toh, t16);
    TEST(16, my_le16toh, t16);

    TEST(32, my_htobe32, t32);
    TEST(32, my_htole32, t32);
    TEST(32, my_be32toh, t32);
    TEST(32, my_le32toh, t32);

    TEST(64, my_htobe64, t64);
    TEST(64, my_htole64, t64);
    TEST(64, my_be64toh, t64);
    TEST(64, my_le64toh, t64);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output on a little endian system:**

```
my_htobe16(0x1234) = 0x3412
my_htole16(0x1234) = 0x1234
my_be16toh(0x1234) = 0x3412
my_le16toh(0x1234) = 0x1234
my_htobe32(0x12345678) = 0x78563412
my_htole32(0x12345678) = 0x12345678
my_be32toh(0x12345678) = 0x78563412
my_le32toh(0x12345678) = 0x12345678
my_htobe64(0x123456789abcdef) = 0xefcdab8967452301
my_htole64(0x123456789abcdef) = 0x123456789abcdef
my_be64toh(0x123456789abcdef) = 0xefcdab8967452301
my_le64toh(0x123456789abcdef) = 0x123456789abcdef
```

**Output on a big endian system (expected, but not tested by me):**

```
my_htobe16(0x1234) = 0x1234
my_htole16(0x1234) = 0x3412
my_be16toh(0x1234) = 0x1234
my_le16toh(0x1234) = 0x3412
my_htobe32(0x12345678) = 0x12345678
my_htole32(0x12345678) = 0x78563412
my_be32toh(0x12345678) = 0x12345678
my_le32toh(0x12345678) = 0x78563412
my_htobe64(0x123456789abcdef) = 0x123456789abcdef
my_htole64(0x123456789abcdef) = 0xefcdab8967452301
my_be64toh(0x123456789abcdef) = 0x123456789abcdef
my_le64toh(0x123456789abcdef) = 0xefcdab8967452301
```

Comment: I'm trying ! I need it to be small endian

Comment: For little-endian, you can use `htole32` to convert a 32-bit value from host byte order to little-endian byte order. See updated answer.

Comment: Network byte order means network byte order. It can be either Big or Little. There's no need to use weird non-standard headers - write endianess-independent code in standard C instead. Why write code that needlessly depends on CPU endianess? Network endianess is bad enough.

Comment: @Lundin I restricted the a.k.a. to "several Internet protocols" because the IETF defines network byte order as big endian. As for the use of non-standard headers, well you could write your own CPU endianness independent equivalent functions if you want (or just write in-line C code to do it as needed, but that gets tedious after a while).

Comment: Protocols need not even be consistent throughout the OSI model. You could have data link frame in one endian, network/transport protocols in one endian and then payload in one endian... all in the same transfer.

Comment: @Lundin TBH, the main reason I mentioned "network byte order" at all is because that's what the `n` in `htonl` etc. stands for.

Comment: Yeah but the OP seems to want to prepare some sort of data protocol too.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, the point is moot because OP is actually using little endian values in their protocol. But I didn't know that when I initially wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `memcpy` but that would make your code dependent on the underlying endianess of the CPU. I don't think that's what you want.

My take is that you want to convert to the ***network endianess*** of whatever data communications protocol this is, ***regardless of CPU endianess***.

The only way to achieve that is bit shifts. The byte order depends on the target network endianess:

```
void u32_to_big_endian (uint8_t* dst, const uint32_t src)
{
  dst[0] = (uint8_t) ((src >> 24) & 0xFFu);
  dst[1] = (uint8_t) ((src >> 16) & 0xFFu);
  dst[2] = (uint8_t) ((src >>  8) & 0xFFu);
  dst[3] = (uint8_t) ((src >>  0) & 0xFFu);
}

void u32_to_little_endian (uint8_t* dst, const uint32_t src)
{
  dst[3] = (uint8_t) ((src >> 24) & 0xFFu);
  dst[2] = (uint8_t) ((src >> 16) & 0xFFu);
  dst[1] = (uint8_t) ((src >>  8) & 0xFFu);
  dst[0] = (uint8_t) ((src >>  0) & 0xFFu);
}
```

In these functions, it doesn't matter what the CPU endianess is. You can forget about memcpy() and non-standard endianess conversion functions. Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void u32_to_big_endian (uint8_t* dst, const uint32_t src)
{
  dst[0] = (uint8_t) ((src >> 24) & 0xFFu);
  dst[1] = (uint8_t) ((src >> 16) & 0xFFu);
  dst[2] = (uint8_t) ((src >>  8) & 0xFFu);
  dst[3] = (uint8_t) ((src >>  0) & 0xFFu);
}

void u32_to_little_endian (uint8_t* dst, const uint32_t src)
{
  dst[3] = (uint8_t) ((src >> 24) & 0xFFu);
  dst[2] = (uint8_t) ((src >> 16) & 0xFFu);
  dst[1] = (uint8_t) ((src >>  8) & 0xFFu);
  dst[0] = (uint8_t) ((src >>  0) & 0xFFu);
}


int main(void)
{
  uint32_t i = 0x00320036u; 
  uint8_t header[54] = {0};

  u32_to_little_endian(&header[2], i);
  for(size_t i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
    printf("%.2x ", (unsigned int)header[i]);
  }
}
```

Output, including the first 2 bytes as zeroes:

```
00 00 36 00 32 00
```